# Split csv file based on column from command line

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, scripting

I have some data in a file in the form of csv of the form:

```
ID,DATE,EARNING
1,12 May 2018,5
1,13 May 2018,15
2,12 May 2018,25
```

I want to split this into multiple files such that file_1_May_report contains:

```
ID,DATE,EARNING
1,12 May 2018,5
1,13 May 2018,15
```

and another file file_2_May_report that contains:

```
ID,DATE,EARNING
2,12 May 2018,25
```

I have tried :

```
awk -F, '{print >> $1}' input.csv
```

However I only get one file 1 with only one record, that is the last record in the input file. How do I get it to split into multiple files based on ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{hdr=$0; next} !seen[$1]++{fn="file_" $1 "_May_report"; print hdr > fn} {print > fn}' input.csv
```

Or with a more readable format:

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 {
   hdr = $0
   next
}
!seen[$1]++ {
   fn = "file_" $1 "_May_report"
   print hdr > fn
}
{
   print > fn
}' input.csv
```

Comment: I had properly tested this awk before posting. Can you clarify what didn't work?

Comment: It doesnt create any files

Comment: This worked. The problem was my file has the wrong line terminators. had to run tr '^M' '\n' <input.csv > unix-input.csv